# div inside anchor tag or div with onclick which is more efficient

Tags: html, asp.net

I had made my own gridview .Now I want to make every row in gridview clickable.

**For example:** when user click on row.Then another page is displayed with more information.

**my first way**

`<div onclick=""></div>`

**my second way**

```
<a href="querystring"><div> this contain images and labels</div></a>
```

I want to know which is more efficient way.

If I use "onclick" this will postback whole page.And
then all input field send back to server.

I think this will slow down the server.

I want to know which way is better and faster

Answer (score 0):

I don't think these are the optimizations you should be concerned about..
Anyway, I think ab anchor is more clear, can be shared and requires less code on your side.
However, if your issue is having an event handler and not going to an element, you should register to the `onclick`